# Name of a beehive like organic structure, is it aromatic?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

I was just studying organic chemistry and came across a weird, yet beautiful, structure, don't know its name but its structure is given below:

[image: my own drawing!!]

I wanted to ask what is the compound's name? Is it aromatic, anti-aromatic, or non-aromatic?
I guess it should be anti-aromatic as it is not following [Huckel's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%BCckel%27s_rule), ig? as total of $16$ $\pi$ electrons are there, so it should be having $4n$ electrons where $n = 4$. But anti-aromatic compounds are *highly unstable* to the extent that they doesn't exist, but this compound seems stable to me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The given compound is Pyrene. Pyrene is a polycyclic aromatic hydrocarbon consisting of four fused benzene rings, resulting in a flat aromatic system. The chemical formula is $C_{16}H_{10}$.

Pyrene is aromatic. The Huckel $(4n+2)π$ rule works best with monocyclic ring systems. If you look at the following resonance structure for pyrene with a central double bond, the monocyclic periphery has 14 π electrons (ignoring the greyed-out central double bond), but that is a rationalization.

Nonetheless, pyrene undergoes reactions characteristic of aromatic systems and has ring currents expected from aromatic systems.

The $(4n+2)π$ rule was really meant to apply to monocyclic pi systems. You run into problems when it is extended beyond its originally intended use.

Comment: Hmmm, but I can't understand how there are 14 pi electrons?

Comment: @Gamin8ing the path around the perimeter gives you 14 π electrons. The huckle rule will be followed if the central two carbons aren't aromatic. But it is controversial.